# Django css no longer working for print after deleting static file

Tags: css, django

I was developing a website using django and the css was working ^retty fine ,i deleted the static directory after facing a problem with loading a picture then i created it once again  , once i  refreshed the css on the page it no longer worked  .

this is my setting.py file :

```
"""
    Django settings for ecommerce project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
    """
    import os
    from os.path import dirname, join, abspath


    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

    #static files upload_to
    # MEDIA_ROOT = join(__dir__, 'static')
    # MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'commandes',
        'contact',
        'evenement',
        'templates',
        'static',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates/')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {

        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'NUTEK',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }

    }

    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    # keep it empty for the moment
```

I appreciate any help .thanks in advance

Comment: Have you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: yes i did ,but it showed 0 static files copied 118 unmodified and when i refresh the page i still face the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) denotes where collectstatic will look for static files for collection, by default this will be the `FileSystemFinder` and `AppDirectoriesFinder`.

`AppDirectoriesFinder` will look in all `<app>/static` directories which is useful for most third party applications.

Your problem is probably the `FileSystemFinder`, you need to define [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) for it to find your static files

Comment: No problem! Happy programming